# How to find the time evolution for two-component spinor?

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, spinors, time-evolution

I would like to find the time evolution for the given Hamiltonian, the initial state of the system we choose two spinor wavefunction $\psi_{+}(t=0)$ and $\psi_{-}(t=0)$ as given below:

The effective Hamiltonian can be written as 
\begin{equation}
H=\nu_{F} {\bf \sigma}\cdot\left(q-By\hat x\right)
\end{equation}
where ${\bf \sigma}=(\sigma_{x},\sigma_{y})$ and $q=(q_{x},q_{y})$ are the Pauli matrices and the momentum operator respectively. Taking the spinor wavefunctions as
\begin{align}
\psi_{+}&=e^{ikx}\\ 
\psi_{-}&=e^{ikx}
\label{eq:wavefs}
\end{align} 
 as the initial condition for the Schrodinger equation. The time evolution of the system,
\begin{equation}
\Psi(r,t)=e^{-i\nu_{F} {\bf \sigma}\cdot\left(q-By\hat x\right)t}\Psi(r,0)
\end{equation}
 and
\begin{equation}
\Psi(r,0)=e^{ikx}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

The matrix exponential for any Pauli matrix using the general formula [see general formula][1]. This procedure gives,

$$\exp[-iHt] = I_{2\times2}\cos \nu_{F}t - i {\bf\sigma}\cdot\left(q-By\hat x\right) \sin \nu_{F}t$$
I tryed to solve using this method but seems not convincing. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: @Qmechanic, could you check my procedure to find the time evolution for the given Hamiltonian and the spinor wavefunction as the initial condition?