# How to solve the Dirac equation numerically?

Tags: dirac-equation, numerical-method

The effective Hamiltonian for my system is:
$$
H=\nu_{F} \sigma\cdot\left(q-By\hat x\right)
$$
where $\sigma$ and $q$ are the Pauli matrices and the momentum operator respectively and $\nu_{F}$ and $B$ are constants. I would like to solve the Dirac equation numerically for the given Hamiltonian. Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: How familiar are you with numerically solving ODE/PDEs?

Comment: @ Kyle Kanos, Not much but I tryed first and have errors

Comment: Related questions by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172242/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169319/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic, yeah but now I am trying to directly solve Dirac equation using the given Hamiltonian. My previous question was having the initial states at t=0. It is more of particular question and I decide to delete.

Comment: @Herman: You may want to investigate more simple equations first (e.g., the [advection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advection) and [diffusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) equations) before trying to tackle the Dirac equation.

Comment: @KyleKanos, thank you for the links. I already understand the solution for the heat equation using this [link](www.lehman.edu/faculty/dgaranin/Mathematical_Physics/Mathematical_physics-13-Partial_differential_equations.pdf)

Comment: Okay, that's not at all what I meant. I meant doing something [like this code of mine](https://github.com/kylekanos/Diffusion1D).

Comment: @KyleKanos, a bit more advanced your code. It takes much time to fully understand your code.

Comment: What stops you from solving this Hamiltonian analytically? Is it because you are considering it with nontrivial geometry/boundary conditions?

Comment: @Herman: Mathematica basically does the same thing as my code, but it hides the details so the only thing you need is the `NDSolve`. I don't doubt that my code takes time to digest, but I suggest taking the time to learn what it's doing.

Comment: @MengCheng, I tryed it but still not convinced. I would like to have the analytical solution.

Comment: @Herman Assume that the system is on an infinite plane, a quick way to get the spectrum is to square the Hamiltonian, which gives the Hamiltonian of a free non-relativistic electron in a magnetic field. The energy level of the latter problem is well-known, i.e. Landau levels. So the "Landau levels" for the Dirac fermion is just the square root. More details can be found here http://mafija.fmf.uni-lj.si/seminar/files/2010_2011/zala_lenarcic.pdf

Comment: @MengCheng, thank you so much for the link and for the comments. Actually, I'm working on polaritonic graphene and the link is related to the research I'm working.